# Реакция actionbar на изменения в активности(фрагменте)

Tags: android, actionbar

Есть активность с `actionbar` и `listview`. При выборе елемента из `listview` хочу чтобы `actionbar` полностью заменялась и новая `actionbar` отображала кнопки для действий с выделенным элементом(В приложениях такое сплошь и рядом). Например появлялась кнопка удалить или изменить... Как это делают? Как это реализуют? Воздействуют на элемент `ActionBar` или поверх создают какой-то лейаут с необходимыми элементами? Может есть линк на урок? А то я не нашел...просто не знаю даже как вопрос для поисковика сформулировать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте для подобных целей [Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html). Вот [Пример](https://habrahabr.ru/post/256643/).

Он удобен и гибкий в настройке.
Не забудьте, что при его использовании необходимо использовать `NoActionBar` темы.

Comment: Да спасибо. Это кажется то что надо. Еще вроде бы это можно реализовать с помощью ActionMode